# C# XmlSerializer.Deserialize fails with certain namespaces

Tags: c#, serialization

I do not have a strong practical understanding of the namespace, xml parsing, etc.
I could not reason why Deserialize only works with one particular namespace and not for others.

First of all, Deserialize did not work with the XML having the DTD definition. I had to remove it. Then it did not work without any namespace defined. I had to add one. Now I am trying to find a reasoning behind this behavior.

This is the code where I see the error (at the Deserialize call) if I do not have the namespace in the XML.

```
Notification rtnn = null;
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Notification));
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"n1.xml");
object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```

Originally the XML came like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Notification SYSTEM "https://indipay.dpmtsrvc.com/dtds/Notif-ver2_0.dtd">
<Notification>
  <BillProductCode>Payment</BillProductCode>
  ...
</Notification>
```

My objective is to get some data from the XML. I was going to use either XmlDocument or XPathNavigator class
As per my code-reviewer recommendation, I end up using the XmlSerializer to convert the XML into an object.
This XML is only DTD based to begin with. This comes from a 3rd party bank.
First I converted the DTD to XSD, then used the XSD.exe tool to create the C# class. This is the command I used

```
C:\develop\tmp\bank>xsd Notification.xsd /c /outputdir:nclass
```

The generated class was like this

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/namespace/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/namespace/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Notification
{
     private BillProductCode billProductCodeField;

   /// <remarks/>
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.18020")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/namespace/")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/namespace/", IsNullable = false)]
   public partial class BillProductCode
   {

    private string[] textField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string[] Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.textField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.textField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As we notice, the directives above the class has this namespace ("http://www.w3.org/namespace/") mentioned in.
This was generated by the xsd tool. And this is because there is no XSD to begin with. So, I could not give a namespace while running xsd.exe. So, the default was this namespace ("http://www.w3.org/namespace/").
**Whatever it is, I would like to confirm if I did not do anything error-prone.**

Another question I have is - If you see the above property class BillProductCode. In order to get the value of the BillProductCode, do I have to go into the string array and get the first item. 
**Shall I not get the value simply like Notification.BillProductCode?**

In DTD, it was like this

```
<!ELEMENT Notification (
    BillProductCode?,...)>
<!ELEMENT BillProductCode (#PCDATA)>
...
```

In XSD, it is generated like this by the tool

```
<schema xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' targetNamespace='http://www.w3.org/namespace/' xmlns:t='http://www.w3.org/namespace/'>
    <element name='Notification'>
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                            <element ref='t:BillProductCode' 
                               minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
                        </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
        ...
    <element name='BillProductCode'>
        <complexType mixed='true'>
        </complexType>
    </element>
        ...
</schema>
```

Comment: Your schema is a top level schema that is not references any parent schema so the default schema is the 2001 standard schema.  Your xml would look like this : <BillProductCode><textField>innertext 1</textField><textField>innertext 2</textField><textField>innertext 3</textField></BillProductCode>  BillProductCode has no innertext while textField has inner text so they are not the same.

Comment: What if I want following when we serialize
<BillProductCode>19034</BillProductCode>

I believe DTD to XSD has made some difference. There are more than one possibility I think. I may have to manually write the XSD looking at both the DTD and XML.

Comment: If I create schema directly from XML, it has like this
<xs:element name="BillProductCode" type="xs:string" />
But the DTD definition contains 
<!ELEMENT BillProductCode (#PCDATA)>
PCDATA appears to represent complex type, so it is translated by the xsd tool like below
<element ref='t:BilrProductCode' minOccurs='0' maxOccurs='1'/>
<element name='BillProductCode'>
   <complexType mixed='true'>
</complexType>
 </element>

Comment: It is probably simpler to generate the classes manually rather than through the tools.  The machine generated classes are adding 5 or 6 lines of attributes that are not needed.  Post a sample of the xml you want and I will give you the very simple classes.

Comment: jdweng - sincere thanks to you. i already got 1 week past my estimated day, and lost my dignity in last status meeting. i will go with the xsd objects as they are, for now.